# PyMeasure: ManagedWindow class doesn't contain directory_input argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, typeerror, qtgui

I'm trying out the latest version 0.8.0 of the PyMeasure package using the examples given in their tutorial from the official documentation. I want to add the directory input to my GUI but I get the error

*TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'directory_input'*

when I run my script. Here is the part of the code where I added this feature according to the [documentation](https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/graphical.html#using-the-directory-input) on the pymeasure readthedoc site.

```py
class MainWindow(ManagedWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(
            procedure_class=RandomProcedure,
            inputs=['iterations', 'delay', 'seed'],
            displays=['iterations', 'delay', 'seed'],
            x_axis='Iteration',
            y_axis='Random Number',
            directory_input=True
        )
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI Example')

    def queue(self):
        directory = self.directory
        filename = unique_filename(directory)
        #filename = tempfile.mktemp()
        

        procedure = self.make_procedure()
        results = Results(procedure, filename)
        experiment = self.new_experiment(results)

        self.manager.queue(experiment)
    
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        QtGui.QApplication.quit()
```

My version check showed that I'm using version 0.8.0, however when I investigated the ManagedWindow class is shows this definition

```py
ManagedWindow(procedure_class, inputs=(), displays=(), x_axis=None, y_axis=None,
log_channel='', log_level=logging.INFO, parent=None, sequencer=False,
sequencer_inputs=None, sequence_file=None, inputs_in_scrollarea=False)
```

which doesn't include the option *directory_input* as an argument.
Does anybody have an idea why this is not available although the versions from the documentation and mine are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the different files that are part of the PyMeasure 0.8.0 package on the GitHub repository and compared these to the ones I got from installing PyMeasure with pip and indeed the lines of code for the implementation of the *directory_input* where missing. I added them manually with the help of an issue thread on [github](https://github.com/pymeasure/pymeasure/pull/322/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.py) which solved the problem.

In short, one needs to adjust the files *widgets.py* and *windows.py* then the feature works.

Comment: Anyhow, I'm still not sure why this happened. Maybe pip gets the package files from a different repository so it's not actually the latest version?